# iOS - hook into .EditingDidEndOnExit

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uidatepicker

I have a series of form fields (UITextField) that have as their "Done" action (which I changed to "Next") the ability to set the firstResponder to the next field down the line, such that when a user is filling out the field they can click next to keep progressing:

```
fields[i-1].addTarget(fields[i], action: "becomeFirstResponder", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.EditingDidEndOnExit)
```

However, in the middle of the form I have a field with a datePicker as the inputView, and I want that same functionality when the user selects a date:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

So basically, the user would select a date and the .EditingDidEndOnExit would fire, which would be handled appropriately by the code above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The date picker emits `.ValueChanged` when the user rotates a wheel. So hook that to whatever you hooked that text field's `.EditingDidEndOnExit` to. Or hook it to something else. But the point is that you can respond directly to the date picker being changed.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar setup but with a Next button on the `inputAccessoryView`:

```
let nextButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "Next", style: .Done, target: self, action: #selector(dismissPicker))
```

And to simulate the return key `EditingDidEndOnExit` event on the associated field, I call `sendActionsForControlEvents`:

```
func dismissPicker() {
    pickerField.resignFirstResponder()
    pickerField.sendActionsForControlEvents(.EditingDidEndOnExit)
}
```